# X11 forwarding to run gvim on ubuntu server

Tags: vim, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, x11-forwarding

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04 and accessing it remotely via "ssh -X". I do not have a desktop environment installed, and would like to keep it that way if possible.
I installed the vim-athena version as it required the least dependencies.
But the gvim window does not open up, and this error is displayed:

> Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion E665: Cannot
>   start GUI, no valid font foundE852: The child process failed to start
>   the GUIXIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server "localhost:11.0"
>         after 9 requests (9 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

What am I missing in the setup?
"xlsfonts" returns a lot of installed fonts.
Also, tkdiff window does pop up, indicating that x11 forwarding is working.